# After Next.js upgrade to 14.1, createElement error from Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, turbopack

I isolated the issue to upgrading Nextjs from 14.0.4 -> 14.1.0.

The issue seems to be stemming from client side instantiation of apollo client. I follow the [guidelines in nextjs for third party package providers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-third-party-packages-and-providers)

**My error**

```
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloConsumer.js
./node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/index.js
./node_modules/@apollo/client/react/index.js
./node_modules/@apollo/client/index.js
./src/lib/apolloClient.js
./src/components/providers.js
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloConsumer.js
Attempted import error: 'createElement' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'React').
```

**My theory**

It could be related to the [new commit pr](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/60840) "Builds will now fail on incorrect usage of useSearchParams without Suspense"

**My question**

Is this an internal issue with apollo client? Do they just need to fix something in their build. I know some of the updates of nextjs have been to turbopack. Or is the issue with how i am splitting up client logic from server logic. however I haven't had this issue before and I am suspect of the new version of nextjs.

**My code**

app/layout.js

```
import React from "react"
import Providers from "../components/providers"

export default function RootLayout({
  // Layouts must accept a children prop.
  // This will be populated with nested layouts or pages
  children,
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

components/providers.js

```
"use client"
import React from "react"
import { useApollo, ApolloClientProvider } from "../lib/apolloClient"

function Providers({ children }) {
  return (
      <ApolloClientProvider>
        {children}
      </ApolloClientProvider>
  )
}

export default Providers
```

lib/apolloClient.js:

```
"use client"

import React, {
  useMemo,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
} from "react"
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, from, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client"
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context"
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error"
// Create a provider for the Apollo client context
export const ApolloClientProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Maintain the JWT in a state
  const [jwt, setJwt] = useState(null)

  const refreshClient = async () => {
    const token = await getAccessJwtToken()
    setJwt(token)
  }

  // refresh client when jwt changes
  useEffect(() => {
    refreshClient()
  }, [jwt])

  const apolloClient = useMemo(() => createApolloClient(jwt), [jwt])

  return (
    <ApolloClientContext.Provider value={{ refreshClient }}>
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>{children}</ApolloProvider>
    </ApolloClientContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be using https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs if you are using the app directory, not `@apollo/client` directly.

I've updated the tests & examples for that to Next 14.1 today and so far everything seemed to be working.

Could you please try it with that package, and if that doesn't work, open an issue there with a reproduction? I'll take a look.